# Too much time taken to run a simple loop

Tags: java, android

I am developing date converter and it converts date into my time. To do that, I have total number of days from beginning of my date to user specified date which calculates total no of days between those time and then I start calculating exact date. The problem is, the loop I am using is taking much longer.

```
// int startingEngYearForSelection = 1944;
// int startingEngMonthForSelection = 1;
//  int startingEngDayForSelection = 1;

int nepYear = startingNepYearForSelection;
int nepMonth = startingNepMonthForSelection;
int nepDay = startingNepDayForSelection;

Log.e("Time Taken", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));

while (totalEngDaysCount != 0)
{
    int daysInIthMonth = EachMonthNumberOfDates.getNepaliMap().get(nepYear)[nepMonth];

    nepDay++;
    if (nepDay > daysInIthMonth) {
        nepMonth++;
        nepDay = 1;
    }
    if (nepMonth > 12) {
        nepYear++;
        nepMonth = 1;
    }

    totalEngDaysCount--;
}
```

This will calculate the days, months and year in my format, but it is taking longer than I think it should. Any help on how I can achieve the task faster?

Edit: 
EachNumberOfDates.getNepaliMap() gives total number of days in a month from other class. 
This is defined as:

```
 nepaliMap.put(2000, new int[] { 0, 30, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 31 });
 nepaliMap.put(2001, new int[] { 0, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30 });
```

Comment: what is the value of totalEngDaysCount ?

Comment: can totalEngDaysCount have a negative value? if so it'll be infinite loop

Comment: I get that from other function, something around 20,000 or plus

Comment: Loop runs fast for smaller date, like I started the date in 1944 and if the selected year is near like 1945,1946 then the calculation is faster but it becomes slow as year is increased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `getNepaliMap` is just returning a field, so is O(1).
- `Map.get`, for almost all `Map` implementations, is O(1).
- Array indexing `[nepMonth]` is O(1).
- All of your integer arithmetic and comparisons are O(1).

There are no optimisations you can make here. You can't make this any faster unless you work out some way to parallelise it.

It's not obvious what you're trying to accomplish but it looks like you may be able to give each thread the responsibility of doing the calculation for a certain period and then combine the result.

Comment: Thanks. I would go with other way around.